# Why is any unbounded subset of the reals not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, real-numbers

Why is any unbounded subset of the reals not compact?

I have that a subset of the reals is compact if every open cover of this subset has a finite sub-cover.

Comment: because the real line is not compact

Answer (score 7):

Take the cover $\{(-n,n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: This was actually suggested to be used but I'm not sure how to apply it. And isn't this just one particular subset of the reals?

Comment: @JohnH No, this is an open cover that is very unlikely to have a finite subcover, whatever your unbounded set of reals may be...

Comment: @JohnH, suppose that exists a finite subcover of the set. How will be the set?

Comment: negative to positive infinity? That is one set (finite), but it has infinitely many elements?

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble grasping the concepts of covers and sub covers

Comment: @JohnH, a cover of $A$ is a family of sets $(B_i)_{i\in I}$ s.t. $A\subset\cup_{i\in I}B_i$.

Comment: Ok, there is no such finite sub cover of the cover {(-n,n)}

Comment: @JohnH, right..

Comment: Could I conclude from there that it is not compact? Since {(-n,n)} is an unbounded subset of R, it is an open cover, but it does NOT have a finite sub cover?

Comment: @JohnH, $\{(-n,n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ **isn't** a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46716/discussion-between-john-h-and-martin-blas-perez-pinilla).

Answer (score 0):

For your unbounded subset of the reals, consider the open cover that consists of the sets $\{O_1, O_2, \dotsc\}$ where $O_i$ is the open ball centered at the origin with radius $i$. This cover admits no finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative definition for compactness, which is logically equivalent to the other one says that a subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Some analysis textbooks take this as THE definition, other use it as an if and only if theorem.

Now you know. It can't be compact because it's not bounded.